# union sign in pseudo code

Tags: union, pseudocode

I'm trying to rewrite an algorithm using python by using pseudo code
but I got confused by the meaning of union sign, Here is what the pseudo code looks like

```
count(l):
counts ← {}.
For each l.x in l:
 For each (c,b) in l.x:
  If, for some n, (c,n) is in counts:
   counts ← counts – {(c,n)} ∪ {(c,n+1)}.
  Else: counts ← counts ∪ {(c,1)}.
Return counts.
```

Here, what is the meaning of

```
counts ← counts – {(c,n)} ∪ {(c,n+1)}.
```

does it  mean counts equals to everything besides the union of (c,n) and(c,n+1) ?
but it seems violates the name of the function, could anyone explain to me what this line of code mean ?

Answer (score 0):

```
counts – {(c,n)} ∪ {(c,n+1)}
```

is meant to be read as

```
(counts – {(c,n)}) ∪ {(c,n+1)}
```

I.e. build the union of

- the `counts` set without the `(c,n)` element
- `{(c,n+1)}`